# maya: cannot rotate ik control in command

Tags: maya

I use maya default human ik example, see my gif, when i rotate in viewport, rotate work, but when i undo and rotate with same command in script editor, it cannot rotate, how to rotate ik control in command
[image]

I try maya 2018 and maya lt 2018, it has same problem

Answer (score 1):

update 18-6-22
I find the solution, maya default doesn't show all commands, I should script editor > history > echo all commands

[image]

I need more code to change ik control in "control rig" status
I select a ik control(like right arm), and run following python code:

```
import maya.mel as mel
import maya.cmds as cmds

mel.eval("hikManipStart 1 1")

cmds.rotate(0,0,73,r=True)

mel.eval("hikManipStop") //
```

it work

My tmp solution is: in human ik toolwin, set "Source" to none, and rotate original joint will work
[image]